# How can one make dry fine hazelnut flour?

Tags: flour, nuts

How can one make a hazelnut flour that is as dry and fine as coconut flour? What is sold as "ground hazelnut" or "hazelnut meal" is coarse and moist.

Comment: Any feedback on below answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over half of the weight of hazelnuts consists of oil.  So just:

- buy / pick the hazelnuts yourself
- buy yourself a decent nut oil press, (the higher the pressure the more oil you will remove)
- press the nuts

and whatever is left after you've pressed all the oil out of the nuts is very dry though still coarse so the only thing left to do is just use a grain grinder to grind that into the smoothest most wonderful flour you've ever seen and tasted.

<sup><sub>**Tip:** if you're only interested in the nut flour, start selling the hazelnut oil as it's a fantastic product to make all kinds of fried desserts like fried chocolate to offset the 2 new items you had to buy</sub></sup>

Comment: This sounds amazing. Have you done this?

Comment: No, i don't have a nut oil press: so I grind them, separate about 20% of the oil (which floats naturally to the top) and use the resulting paste in desserts or to make my own chocolate spread, but if I'd be serious about using nut flour to make bread, the above is _how I would do it..._